# Launching a python script as a background job on Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to run a `*.py` file as a background service in *Jupiter notebook*.

```
from IPython.lib import backgroundjobs as bg
jobs = bg.BackgroundJobManager()
jobs.new(%run -i "script.py") # Not working
jobs.new("script.py") # Not working
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ipython/Jupyter background jobs are designed to run either plain code to [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) (string), or function. Files and ipython magic commands are not supported.

One thing you can do is to simply read file content and pass it to `eval`:

```
from IPython.lib.backgroundjobs import BackgroundJobFunc

with open('script.py') as code:
    job = BackgroundJobFunc(exec, code.read())

result = job.run()
```

[`BackgroundJobManager`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.backgroundjobs.html?highlight=BackgroundJobManager#IPython.lib.backgroundjobs.BackgroundJobManager) is pretty much the same, but a little bit "smarter".

Side note: all background machinery behind this interfaces runs in threads of the same process and share interpreter state and output. So, just keep in mind:

- this is not suited for computational-heavy scripts
- never run untrusted code this way — this applies to `eval` overall, but in this case you can into situation when you'll never get GIL back to your "frontend" thread
- avoid scripts that use stdout, most probably those will clutch with your main thread